# Next.js server side imports one file several times in dev mode

Tags: next.js

In dev mode, there's unexpected behavior for nextjs.

I have an event bus shared that I'd like to use in several API calls (one of them is a websocket handler, but it doesn't matter much in the context of the question)

I get my global variable initialized several times, by the number of different API routes.

I.e. `/components/shared.ts`:

```
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

export const sharedUuid = v4();
```

`pages/api/hello.ts`:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { sharedUuid } from '../../components/shared';

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  console.log("sharedUuid on a page", sharedUuid);
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

`pages/api/hello2.ts`:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { sharedUuid } from '../../components/shared';

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  console.log("sharedUuid on a page 2", sharedUuid);
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

On separate calls, would yield not the same `sharedUuid` but different ones!

```
sharedUuid on a page 3f136fc0-b2ed-49b7-90b4-d0a680a9c922

sharedUuid on a page 2 931b83bc-09ea-4165-be0a-884516cf4bf3
```

It seems next.js recreates the whole app anew for each of the routes.

I'd like to have a shared file loaded only once. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Salvaged a solution from [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15054#discussioncomment-658138):

```
export class GlobalRef<T> {
  private readonly sym: symbol;

  constructor(uniqueName: string) {
    this.sym = Symbol.for(uniqueName);
  }

  get value() {
    return (global as any)[this.sym] as T | undefined;
  }

  set value(value: T) {
    (global as any)[this.sym] = value;
  }
}
```

then, whenever you want to use your global:

```
export const databaseConn = new GlobalRef('myapp.database');
if (!databaseConn.value) {
  databaseConn.value = setupDatabaseConnection();
}
```

Then use global as `databaseConn.value;`